# Hey Guys I keep on having syntax errors with Python, this is my first day doing python ever please give me grace

Tags: python, syntax, madlib

Im trying to do a madlib game and keep having syntax errors but Im following a video but getting a complete different result.

I tried to eliminate the error but it keeps on going to the next cursor

madlib():
print( "welcome to my mad lib")

```
pronoun1=input ("fans")
first name=input ("jeremy")
noun1=input ("tree")
last name=input ("thomas")
second pronoun=input("stars")
place=input ("broward")
third pronoun=input ("lions")
place2=input ("LA")
fourth pronoun=input("moons")
noun2=input ("chair")
adjective1=input("sharp")
adjective2=input("smelly")
verb=input("fighting")
adjective3=input("tall ")

print "hello there, sports",pronoun1, "this is" first name"talking to you from the press" noun1 "in" last name "stadium, where 57,000 cheering" second pronoun "have gathered to watch the" place third pronoun "take on the"  place 2 fourth pronoun "even though the"  noun2 "is shining, its a" adjective1 "cold day with the temperatrue in the" adjective2 "2os. We'll be back for the opening " verb "after a few words from our" adjective3 "sponsor"
```

Comment: Please check out [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: you cant have spaces in variables, "first_name" or firstName" instead of "first name"

Comment: `input` asks the user to type something and stores what they type inside the variable. Is that what you want? It seems more like you want to store the text inside `input` in the variable. If so, remove the `input`.

Comment: This isn't what is causing the syntax error, I'm just warning you of a possible unintended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In the lines where you're asking for input, you should not include any spaces in the variable names. Instead of first name, you should use first_name, like this:

```
first_name = input("Jeremy")
```

In the print statement at the end, you should use parentheses around the string you're trying to print. Also, you're missing a plus sign in a few places where you're trying to concatenate strings. Here's a corrected version of the print statement:

```
print("Hello there, sports " + pronoun1 + ", this is " + first_name + " talking to you from the press " + noun1 + " in " + last_name + " Stadium, where 57,000 cheering " + second_pronoun + " have gathered to watch the " + place + " " + third_pronoun + " take on the " + place2 + " " + fourth_pronoun + ". Even though the " + noun2 + " is shining, it's a " + adjective1 + " cold day with the temperature in the " + adjective2 + " 20s. We'll be back for the opening " + verb + " after a few words from our " + adjective3 + " sponsor.")
```

These changes should help eliminate the syntax errors in your code.

I hope this helps and good luck with your project!

Comment: Hello, I hate to be a pest but now code has no syntax error but after running the code "import madlib" it does not work.

Comment: What does the error say exactly?

Comment: Also input() will safe the console input of the user to the  variable + the argument of input is the description when you are entering it later: in this case "fans{here your input in the console, safed in the var pronoun1 when running}" -- As you see the "fans" in the input makes no sense. If you want to safe it in the varible without inputing, than just remove the input and the parentheses.

Comment: And sorry for my missconception regarding the import. It is not required, as you are not refering to any extern library.